# Typescript: Type representing a generic React component or HTML element, and its props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm writing a quick wrapper interface. I'm looking for some mystery types:

**Let** `Foo` be some React component that accepts props of type `FooProps`.

**Let** `X` be the interface that represents both any generic React component or any HTML element. Where `Foo extends X` but also `div extends X`. `X` is anything that can be turned into a JSX.Element by `<X></X>`

**Let** `Y<T extends X>` be the props of our `T`, which is again any element such as `Foo` or `div`. Where `Y<Foo> = FooProps`, and `Y<div> = { className: string, ... }`

We could write:

```
interface WrapperProps<T extends X>{
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    attributes?: Y<T>;
}
```

Then we could write:

```
const props: WrapperProps<T> = ...;
const el: JSX.Element = (
    <T {...attributes}>
        { children }
    </T>
);
```

**What are these mystery types `X` and `Y`?**

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```ts
type WrapperProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> = {
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    attributes: Omit<React.ComponentProps<T>, 'children'>;
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVnqBN)

Notice the required `attributes` property. While you can make any of the properties optional you cannot omit them at all.

React types used here:

[JSX.IntrinsicElements](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L3060-L3240) (too big to include here).

`JSXElementConstructor`:

```ts
type JSXElementConstructor<P> =
    | ((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null)
    | (new (props: P) => Component<P, any>);
```

`ReactComponentProps`:

```ts
type ComponentProps<T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | JSXElementConstructor<any>> =
    T extends JSXElementConstructor<infer P>
        ? P
        : T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
            ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
            : {};
```